# How to put labels at a specific point on any resolution

Tags: unity, resolution, scene

I am working on a project in Unity 4.6.1 and I put the label at the top: [image]

But when I put the Scene in full view this happened:

[image]

I made a Development Build and when I select my resolution (1366x768) the label goes behind the buttons. Is there any way to put the label at a specific point no matter what resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Title in your hierarchy. In the Rect transform, you can see that square in the editor. Click it, you can then set the position of the Text (Top, in you case.) After that, press Alt, and choose where to place your Anchor. (Top again). If you still don't like it, you can choose to move the Anchor manually in the Scene. Ultimately, keep the Anchor close to the object's center, so it's always well positionned.

Here is a quick animation : http://gfycat.com/HonorableAcrobaticArcticfox

Comment: How do I change the Anchor because when I open the Rect transform square and press Alt nothing happens. I tried clicking and dragging and nothing happened and I tried pressing the arrow keys but nothing happened.

Comment: Here, I edited my answer so you can see.

Comment: OK I get it now.